# Why is my systemd timer inactive after reboot or resume although it is enabled

Tags: linux, reboot, systemd, wake-up, timer

I have created a SystemD timer to trigger a service but my timer does not start after PC reboot or resume although it is enabled :

```shell
$ sudo reboot
....AFTER reboot...
$ systemctl is-enabled ncc-record.timer
enabled
$ systemctl is-active ncc-record.timer
inactive
$ systemctl cat ncc-record.timer
# /usr/local/lib/systemd/system/ncc-record.timer
[Unit]
Description=Trigger the service record.service
[Timer]
OnCalendar=Sun *-*-* 11:29:30
[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
$ systemctl status ncc-record.timer
○ ncc-record.timer - Trigger the service record.service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/local/lib/systemd/system/ncc-record.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
    Trigger: n/a
   Triggers: ● ncc-record.service
$
```

EDIT0 : I added a newline after the last directive of each section of the timer and moved the timer into `/lib/systemd/system/` :

```shell
$ sudo mv -v /usr/local/lib/systemd/system/ncc-record.timer /lib/systemd/system/ncc-record.timer
copied '/usr/local/lib/systemd/system/ncc-record.timer' -> '/lib/systemd/system/ncc-record.timer'
removed '/usr/local/lib/systemd/system/ncc-record.timer'
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload 
$ systemctl cat ncc-record.timer
# /lib/systemd/system/ncc-record.timer
[Unit]
Description=Trigger the service record.service

[Timer]
OnCalendar=Sun 8:29:30

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
$ sudo systemctl disable ncc-record.timer;sudo systemctl enable ncc-record.timer
Removed /etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/ncc-record.timer.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/ncc-record.timer → /lib/systemd/system/ncc-record.timer.
$ sudo systemctl start ncc-record.timer
$ sudo reboot
.........AFTER REBOOT
$ systemctl is-active ncc-record.timer
inactive
$ journalctl -u ncc-record.timer -b
sept. 04 20:47:49 seb-EB1501P systemd[1]: ncc-record.timer: Refusing to start, unit ncc-record.service to trigger not loaded.
sept. 04 20:47:49 seb-EB1501P systemd[1]: Failed to start Trigger the service record.service.
$ last reboot -1
reboot   system boot  6.2.0-31-generic Mon Sep  4 20:47   still running

wtmp begins Thu Jun  8 19:31:53 2023
$ systemd-analyze verify /etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/ncc-record.timer
$ systemd-analyze calendar "Sun 8:29:30"
  Original form: Sun 8:29:30
Normalized form: Sun *-*-* 08:29:30
    Next elapse: Sun 2023-09-10 08:29:30 CEST
       (in UTC): Sun 2023-09-10 06:29:30 UTC
       From now: 5 days left
$ sudo systemctl start ncc-record.timer 
Job failed. See "journalctl -xe" for details.
$ journalctl -xe -u ncc-record.timer | tail -9
sept. 04 21:23:46 seb-EB1501P systemd[1]: ncc-record.timer: Refusing to start, unit ncc-record.service to trigger not loaded.
sept. 04 21:23:46 seb-EB1501P systemd[1]: Failed to start Trigger the service record.service.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit ncc-record.timer has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit ncc-record.timer has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 3152 and the job result is failed.
$
```

EDIT1 : I also add to move the service into the same directory (`/lib/systemd/system/`) of the timer, problem solved :)

Comment: Is it possible that the unit files are stored on a drive partition that is mounted at boot after systemd loaded the timers (pointing to them with symlinks)?

Comment: @harrymc My timer is stored in the `/usr/local` LVM logical volume which is automatically mounted at boot, can this be a problem ?

Comment: @harrymc I tried to add `usr-local.mount` to the `WantedBy=` directive and did a `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and then rebooted but it still did not start my timer.

Comment: As a test, you could try moving it to the system disk.

Comment: @harrymc You can take a look at my EDIT0 where I did what you asked.

Comment: Sorry, I have no more suggestions.

Comment: @harrymc I also add to move the service into the same directory of the timer, problem solved :) Now, if want them both into `/usr/local/lib/systemd/system/`, how do I do that ?